# Как решить проблему с подключением к mysql?

Tags: python, mysql

Пытаюсь подключиться к mysql.

Вот мой код:

```
import pymysql

my_db = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password=''
)

my_cursor = my_db.cursor()
my_cursor.execute('SHOW DATABASES')
for db in my_cursor:
    print(db)
```

Вот вывод в терминале:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

О правильности данных можете даже не спрашивать, я уже сто раз проверил, они верны.

Comment: Похоже на магию. Ваш код вполне работает при корректных настройках для подключения к базе данных на локальном хосте и наличии установленной библиотеки PyMySQL. Что говорит pip 3 list?

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо указать название базы данных, к которой вы хотите подключиться.

```
import pymysql

my_db = pymysql.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    password='',
    database='имя_базы_данных'
)

my_cursor = my_db.cursor()
my_cursor.execute('SHOW DATABASES')
for db in my_cursor:
    print(db)
```

Comment: Я пробовал. В workbench по умолчанию уже есть три бд. Я пробовал подключиться к одной из них, но ничего не поменялось.

Comment: Кстати, если попробовать создать бд с помощью python, то так же ничего не выходит